# How do I install the btrfs-restore utility on 12.04?

Tags: kubuntu, filesystem, ppa, btrfs

I would like to install btrfs-restore on Kubuntu 12.04

`apt-cache search btrfs-restore` returns nothing.

Google `"ubuntu download OR install btrfs-restore"` returns nothing useful.

Also, where do I get btrfs help? I'm not getting any replies on #btrfs on freenode.net. (Correction: I was too impatient. #btrfs was **very** helpful!)

UPDATE: the previously accepted answer no longer works, so I unselected it as the answer. The PPA dmitrij.ledkov/ppa is missing now. Thanks to Pkunk at #btrfs, I posted a new solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ppa:dmitrij.ledkov is missing now, so the prior solution doesn't exactly work (although the idea is the same).

Use these steps:

1. check the "other versions" under https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/btrfs-tools
2. at the time of this answer, http://launchpad.net/~yofel/+archive/btrfs has a current version of btrfs-tools for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Install using the next steps.
3. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yofel/btrfs
4. sudo apt-get update
5. **if installing new**: sudo apt-get install btrfs-tools
6. **if upgrading**: sudo apt-get --show-upgraded dist-upgrade (or similar)

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Getting `btrfs-restore`

`btrfs-restore` is part of recent `btrfs-tools` packages in Ubuntu; unfortunately the one in Precise dates from 2010 and doesn't contain `btrfs-restore`.

The solution is to add the package from a PPA; this PPA is from the *maintainer of btrfs-tools for Ubuntu*, and contains the same version that is currently in 12.10 Alpha.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:dmitrij.ledkov/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install btrfs-tools
```

Alternately, you can directly install the Quantal debs with `dpkg -i`: for [i386](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/btrfs-tools/0.19+20120328-4ubuntu1/+build/3604206/+files/btrfs-tools_0.19%2B20120328-4ubuntu1_i386.deb) or [amd64](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/btrfs-tools/0.19+20120328-4ubuntu1/+build/3604203/+files/btrfs-tools-dbg_0.19%2B20120328-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb)

#### 2. Getting *btrfs* support

IME, unless you are trying to recover data from a hard-drive which is going to blow up within the hour (or similar exigency), your best bet for informed support is the [official btrfs mailing list](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Btrfs_mailing_list).

Comment: One other option is to just install from git source: see https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Btrfs_source_repositories